# Sorting an array where keys are timestamps by reverse order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, timestamp

Is [`krsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) function suitable for sorting (by reverse order) an array where keys are **timestamps**? Is there (maybe) another "standard" function for doing this?

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1327305600] = '87718';
$arr[1327132800] = '87798';

// Dunno if SORT_NUMERIC is really necessary?
krsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly suitable, you should use the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag. It isn't required as regular sorting will take integers first - but it could prevent future problems.

Comment: What kind of "future problems"? Thanks.

Comment: Someone making modifications to other parts of your application that could influence your sorting by automaticly relying on `natural sorting`.

Answer (score 1):

`krsort()`is fine if the timestamps are the number of seconds (or milliseconds) since an epoch, say, the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). `SORT_NUMERIC` is not necessary if you are sure that all keys are Unix timestamps.